# Given a connected directed graph D, show $\sum_{v\in V_{D}} |deg^{+}(v)-deg^{-}(v)|\le 2(|V_{D}|-1).$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, summation, proof-writing, graph-connectivity

Given a *simple connected directed graph* $D$, show that:

$$\sum_{v\in V_{D}} |d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}| \le 2(|V_{D}|-1).$$

$V_{D}$ is the *vertex-set* and $A_{D}$ is the *arc-set* of $D$. $d^{+}_{v}$ and $d^{-}_{v}$ are the *out-degree* and *in-degree* of vertex $v$.

I have been trying to solve this mostly with the properties that this equality brings $\sum_{v\in V_{D}} |d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}| = \sum_{v\in V_{D}} max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})-min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})$. But so far I've been hitting brick walls, so I thought maybe one of you wizards could enlighten me.

**Updated on 23.4.2017**

Although there's nothing really to add here since the conjecture was disproven. I'd like to prove the actual greatest value $\sum_{v\in V_{D}} |d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}|$ can have, for some *simple connected directed graph*.

$(T1)$ $2(\sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})+|V_{D}|-1)\ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}} |d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}|$.

$(L1)$ If a simple directed graph is connected then $|A_{D}| \ge |V_{D}|-1,$

$(L2)$ $2|A_{D}| = \sum_{v\in V_{D}} max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})+min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})$.

$(P1)$ Let $D$ be a *simple connected directed graph*, then

$$|A_{D}| \ge |V_{D}|-1 \tag*{(by P1 and L1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v}) + min(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})\right) \ge |V_{D}|-1  \tag*{(by L2)}$$
$$-|V_{D}|-1\ge -\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v}) + min(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})\right)$$
$$-2(|V_{D}|-1)\ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}-max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v}) - min(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})$$
$$2\left(\sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})-|V_{D}|+1\right) \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v}) - min(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})$$
$$2\left(\sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^+_{v}, d^-_{v})-|V_{D}|+1\right)\ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}} |d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}| \tag*{($\therefore P1$)  $\blacksquare$.}$$

Let's also prove the trivial greatest value of $\sum_{v\in V_{D}}|d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}|$, that is $2|A_{D}|$.

$(T2)$ $\sum_{v\in V_{D}}|d^{+}_{v}-d^{-}_{v}| \le 2|A_{D}|$.

$(L3)$ $2|A_{D}| \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v}) \ge |A_{D}| \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v}) \ge 0.$

$$2|A_{D}| \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v}) \tag*{(by L3)}$$
$$2|A_{D}|-\sum_{v\in V_{D}}min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v}) \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})-min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})$$
$$2|A_{D}| \ge 2|A_{D}|-\sum_{v\in V_{D}}min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})\tag*{(by L3)}$$
$$2|A_{D}| \ge \sum_{v\in V_{D}}max(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v})-min(d^{+}_{v},d^{-}_{v}) \tag*{($\therefore P2$)  $\blacksquare$.}$$

Comment: Did you mean to write $2(|A_{D}|-1)$ instead of $2(|V_{D}|-1)$?

Comment: No, I meant $2(|V_{D}|-1)$, why? Did you find a counter example?

Comment: I thought so for the moment, but no. I wondered why you had introduced $A_D$ in the first place.

Comment: Good point. I'll remove it since it kinda isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to be a counterexample.

Consider a complete bipartite directed graph with partition $A,B$, where $|A|=|B|=n$ (there are all possible edges from $A$ to $B$). Add one additional vertex $c$ and all possible edges from $B$ to $c$ and from $c$ to $A$. Thus obtained graph $D$ is connected.

We calculate that $\mathrm{LHS} = 2n \cdot (n-1)$ grows quadratically and $\mathrm{RHS} = 2 ((2n+1)-1)$ grows linearly with respect to $n$.

For this particular $D$, the claim would work for $|A_D|$ instead of $|V_D|$ - this is why I asked about it in the comments.

Comment: Beautiful and quick! I've been trying to prove myself correct for over a week, when if I'd have been looking for a way of formulating a counterexample and prove that the conjecture is wrong, I would've probably had more luck and less headaches. Lessons learned, thank you.